# Number of increments through period in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I think this question is gonna be hard to solve.
I have a TABLE in my DDBB as this one:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | MONTH  | VALUE |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  | 1-2000 | 20.00 |
| 1  | 2-2000 | 21.00 |
| 1  | 3-2000 | 7.00  |
| 1  | 4-2000 | 8.00  |
+----+--------+-------+
```

With the following definition:

```
ID      INTEGER(7) ZEROFILL NOT NULL
MONTH   VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
VALUE   DOUBLE(20,2)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the way to retrieve the number of times, through a period, the field {VALUE} has increased from its previous values.
In the example above, if the period is from "1-2000" to "4-2000", {VALUE} has increased 2 times: [20.00->21.00, 7.00->8.00]

At the end, I will like to have the following output:

```
+----+------------+
| ID | NUM_OF_INC |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 2          |
+----+------------+
```

What I'm pointing as the main issue, is that {MONTH} is not a DATE type field (of course, it cannot be).

Is there any way to achieve this?
I'm afraid that the solution is to get all the values and then compare one by one from the engine that is executing the queries.

Comment: First of - why your `month` can not have usual date type?

Comment: Client requirements. Odd, isn't it?

Comment: Don't realize stupid client requirements! Even though you might solve this problem, there are more to follow and some might be unsolvable. Imagine you are a dentist and your patient asks you to fix his teeth with an air hammer. You have the ability to use the word "No".

Answer (score 0):

Due to your date format and MySQLs lack of CTEs to convert them a single time, the query gets pretty verbose; this searches the whole range but it's fairly easy to add a range check using the same pattern;

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) NUM_OF_INC
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table1 b
  ON a.id = b.id
 AND a.value < b.value
 AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.`MONTH`, '-1'), '%c-%Y-%d')
   < STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(b.`MONTH`, '-1'), '%c-%Y-%d')
LEFT JOIN Table1 c
  ON a.id = c.id
 AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.`MONTH`, '-1'), '%c-%Y-%d')
   < STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.`MONTH`, '-1'), '%c-%Y-%d')
 AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.`MONTH`, '-1'), '%c-%Y-%d')
   < STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(b.`MONTH`, '-1'), '%c-%Y-%d')
WHERE c.id IS NULL
GROUP BY a.id;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d63d1/2).

Sadly, this query will definitely not use any index you have on `MONTH`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option consider changing the datatype of MONTH into something calculable. Then you can join the last month (Month - 1) and select on a difference > 0:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID, count(*)
  FROM
    Entity t1
  INNER JOIN Entity t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
       AND t2.MONTH = t1.MONTH - 1
  WHERE
    t1.VALUE - t2.VALUE > 0
    AND t1.MONTH BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate
  GROUP BY t1.ID
```

If you can't change the data type. You have to change the `t1.MONTH - 1` with some MySQL functions:

```
DATE_FORMAT(
  SUBDATE(
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t1.MONTH, "-1"), "%c-%Y-%d"),
    INTERVAL 1 MONTH),
  "%c-%Y")
```

as well as `t1.MONTH BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate`:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t1.MONTH, "-1"), "%c-%Y-%d")
    BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate
```